# Python Tibber module just return latest value, not a loop

Tags: python, asynchronous

Ultimately I want to write a value into a database.

I found a script to output desired data.
However it does return it in a loop - but I only need one single value each time I trigger the script, not a loop.

```
import tibber

account = tibber.Account("tokenstring")
home = account.homes[0]


@home.event("live_measurement")
async def process_data(
        data):
    print(data.power)


home.start_live_feed(user_agent="Homey/10.0.0")

print(home.event("live_measurement"))`
```

This will output values in a loop - but I only need one value each time the code runs.

Help!

Comment: _but I only need one value_ So, call the function and take only the first value it returns.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Once I run it, it enters a loop and won’t stop the output. I tried to put the value in a list and run it in a loop while the length of the list is 1 or less, but once it runs it doesn’t check for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve it and put it into a callable fuction.

```
def get_tibber():
    account = tibber.Account(f"{TIBBER_API_KEY}")
    home = account.homes[0]

    @home.event("live_measurement")
    async def process_data(data):
        pass

    def my_exit_function(live_measurement_data):
        global cons
        cons = live_measurement_data.power
        return cons != 0

    # Now start retrieving live measurements
    home.start_live_feed(exit_condition=my_exit_function,
                         user_agent="UserAgent/0.0.1")
    return cons
```